# Executing multiple PHP scripts in parallel, and being notified when finished

Tags: php, multithreading, parallel-processing, exec

So, that's what I'm trying to do - pretty self-explanatory actually :

- Initiate X 'simultaneous' processes (each bound to a different php script)
- Be able to say when *all of them* are finished

I've had a look at various different approaches, and I'm probably going to use `exec` and background processes. (Something along [these lines](http://www.d-mueller.de/blog/parallel-processing-in-php/)).

The thing - which I really can't get my head around - is :

I can't figure out **which is the most efficient way to check whether ALL of the processes are finished** *(being able to keep an eye on the general progress - e.g. X out of Y finished, is also a must)*.

What is important is time-efficiency, and - obviously - not causing any unnecessary server overload (so, I suppose any 'frozen' `while` loop checking for live `pid`s, even if at intervals, is out of the question, right?)

ANY suggestions are very much welcome!

---

***P.S.:** I've initially set this whole thing up with asynchronous Ajax requests starting from the client-side, but I'm currently considering a migration to a non-javascript fully-server-side environment. The issue with parallel-processing though remains...*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should investigate the pcntl_fork and related functions.  This allows one master process to form a number of child processes and be notified of child exit status.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php

Comment: As mike says forking is by far your best bet. I wrote an article about this a long time ago with sample code that you can use. I used it for sending out a huge list of text messages with forking, but you can use it for what you are doing: http://jservedio.com/article/3