# How to get PHP script use more CPU for simple looping task?

Tags: php

I have a simple script that tries to find MD5 collisions via brute force.

```
// Pseudo:
while (runtime < 25 seconds) {
  random_hash1 = random_hash();
  random_hash2 = random_hash();

  if (random_hash1 == random_hash2) {
    notify_user();
  }
}
```

It's working fine itself but I only get around 8 million iterations during this 25 second window. During the run my cpu usage stays at 0-1%. I'm running on 4 cores at 3.8ghz. How can I utilize my cpu more with PHP?

If I did this with java or c++ I would instantly eat whole CPU with my while (1) loop and the iteration count would boost up a lot but I would like to do this with PHP.

PS. I know finding collision is impropable but I do it for fun.

Comment: I think you can try run it in parallel threads. Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747304/executing-multiple-php-scripts-in-parallel-and-being-notified-when-finished

Answer (score 0):

> How can I utilize my cpu more with PHP?

You could try a multi-threading approach using [pthreads](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads)

From the documentation:

> [pthreads](https://php.net/manual/en/intro.pthreads.php) is an Object Orientated API that allows user-land
>   multi-threading in PHP. It includes all the tools you need to create
>   multi-threaded applications targeted at the Web or the Console. PHP
>   applications can create, read, write, execute and synchronize with
>   Threads, Workers and Stackables.